# How to share input value and select option value in a field from Tab view?

Tags: javascript, tabs

I have a Tab option like the following image. Total view will share fixed value for both filed of first tab view.
But when I will take value from datepicker or writing manually in input text field, It will not take the fixed value of Total view.

[image]

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When You clicked on button just make the radio type 'false' . So when you return back radio option will be always unchecked either you click it again.

Just add following jQuery code at the end of your function.

```js
  $('input[type="radio"]').each(function () {
               $(this).attr('checked', false);
            });
```